# Work with one dbContext and multiple connection string in EntityFramework and .net core dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm working in a project  using *EntityFramework* *Core* and *.net core 2.0*, which I need to connect to multiple databases to get data to execute  a cron, I injected `DbContext.cs` in  `startup.cs` like above:

```
  services.AddDbContext<DbContext.cs>();
```

I use it in my  `UnitOfWork.cs` like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork<Context> : IUnitOfWork where Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbContext _context { get; set; }

        public DbContext getContext()
        {
            return _context;
        }
        public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
}
```

which is also managed by dependency injection.

My question is, is it possible to work with a one injected instance of dbcontext, and change the connection at runtime in need? I really  didn't find a clear solution for that. I tried to use a setter and to instantiate a new dbContext every time I need to connect to a new database, but it doesn't seem so beautiful:

```
public void SetContext(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
public DbContext _context { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to work with a one injected instance of dbcontext, and change the connection at runtime in need,

No.  If your Unit Of Work needs to connect to multiple databases, you need multiple DbContext instances.

Comment: so there is no way to change connection string in runtime and connect to different databases using the same `DbContext `?

Comment: No.  You must use a separate DbContext for each database.